# Media Session Compat not showing Lockscreen controls on Pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-5.0-lollipop, lockscreen

I'm using `MediaSessionCompat` from AppCompat Support Library Revision 22. And on Lollipop I'm getting notification & also the background of lockscreen is the album art. And everything works cool.

While on Pre-Lollipop devices, the music controls on lockscreen are not at all shown. It's weird & I tried everything but it doesn't show up, not even the background changes.

I hope someone has solution to this issue.

Note: `RemoteControlClient` used to work on Lollipop & KitKat

```
/**
 * Initializes the remote control client
 */
private void setupMediaSession() {
    /* Activate Audio Manager */
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

    ComponentName mRemoteControlResponder = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
            MediaButtonReceiver.class.getName());
    final Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(mRemoteControlResponder);
    mMediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplication(), "JairSession", mRemoteControlResponder, null);
    mMediaSessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    PlaybackStateCompat playbackStateCompat = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP
            )
            .setState(
                    isPlaying() ? PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING : PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED,
                    getCurrentPosition(),
                    1.0f)
            .build();
    mMediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState(playbackStateCompat);
    mMediaSessionCompat.setCallback(mMediaSessionCallback);
    mMediaSessionCompat.setSessionActivity(retrievePlaybackActions(5));
    mMediaSessionCompat.setActive(true);
    updateMediaSessionMetaData();
    mTransportController = mMediaSessionCompat.getController().getTransportControls();
```

---

Here's the `updateMediaSessionMetaData()` :

```
/**
 * Updates the lockscreen controls, if enabled.
 */
private void updateMediaSessionMetaData() {
            MediaMetadataCompat.Builder builder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();
            builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, getArtistName());
            builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, getAlbumName());
            builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, getTrackName());
            builder.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, getDuration());
            builder.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, MusicUtils.getArtwork(this, getAlbumID(), true));
            mMediaSessionCompat.setMetadata(builder.build());
```

}

---

The Media Session Callback methods

```
private final MediaSessionCompat.Callback mMediaSessionCallback = new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
        final String intentAction = mediaButtonEvent.getAction();
        if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intentAction)) {
            if (PrefUtils.isHeadsetPause(getBaseContext())) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Headset disconnected");
                pause();
            }
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            final KeyEvent event = mediaButtonEvent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if (event == null) return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
            final int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
            final int action = event.getAction();
            final long eventTime = event.getEventTime();
            if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keycode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK:
                        if (eventTime - mLastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK) {
                            playNext(mSongNumber);
                            mLastClickTime = 0;
                        } else {
                            if (isPlaying())
                                pause();
                            else resume();
                            mLastClickTime = eventTime;
                        }
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
                        mTransportController.stop();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                        if (isMediaPlayerActive()) {
                            if (isPlaying()) mTransportController.pause();
                            else mTransportController.play();
                        }
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                        mTransportController.skipToNext();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                        mTransportController.skipToPrevious();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                        mTransportController.pause();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                        mTransportController.play();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
        super.onPlay();
        resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToNext() {
        super.onSkipToNext();
        playNext(mSongNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipToPrevious() {
        super.onSkipToPrevious();
        playPrevious(mSongNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(long pos) {
        super.onSeekTo(pos);
        seekTo(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        pause();
        commitMusicData();
        updatePlayingUI(STOP_ACTION);
        stopSelf();
    }
};
```

---

Media Button Receiver Manifest Entry

```
<!-- Media button receiver -->
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.MediaButtonReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

---

I'm trying since couple of weeks to solve this issue with no success, and in desperate need of help.

Edit: A tutorial or example of MediaSessionCompat would also be fine

Comment: Revision 22.0 or 22.2? Can you include your code you use to create your `MediaSessionCompat` and where you `setActive()`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake You sure, I'll add the code

Comment: Can you confirm you are using version 22.2.0 of the v4-support library? For debugging purposes, can you include whether `mMediaSessionCompat.isActive()` returns `true` and if `mMediaSessionCompat.getRemoteControlClient()` returns non-null on your Kitkat device right after all of the code you've posted runs?

Comment: @ianhanniballake
Thanks for the suggestion. I did that on Lollipop it gives `mMediaSessionCompat.isActive()` returns `true` and if `mMediaSessionCompat.getRemoteControlClient()` returns `null`.
I'll check on KitKat soon

Comment: @ianhanniballake I checked on KitKat, `mMediaSessionCompat.isActive()` returns `true` and if `mMediaSessionCompat.getRemoteControlClient()` returns non-null.
Yet no lockscreen controls :(

Comment: @ianhanniballake
Is this because I'm not using `Notifications.MediaStyle` to show Notification of Playback.
Actually I'm using Custom Notification.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I used Notifications.MediaStyle yet not working on Pre-Lollipop devices

Comment: What version of the Support Library are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake It's the latest v22.0

Comment: The latest version is 22.2.0 - can you update to that and confirm this is still an issue?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I did typo mistake in above comment, I use v22.2.0. And yet not working.
But it does work on `Lollipop`

Comment: @ianhanniballake I updated few things in the question. Mainly the code

Comment: "I'm planning to test it on Real Device" -- I would never use an emulator for testing lockscreen behaviors like this. I would not be comfortable `MediaSessionCompat` or `RemoteControlClient` uses without testing it on at least a dozen devices, from a variety of manufacturers. That being said, I have never used `MediaSessionCompat` nor `RemoteControlClient`, so I have no specific fixes to suggest.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Trying to show the lockscreen artwork for chromecast. to no avail. any ideas? much appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752191/chromecast-sender-v2-7-0-lockscreen-image

Comment: @Akshay Chordia please can you provide complete code for this actually i am new to android and unable to understand the media sessions and all these things and how to use these things in notification or If you provide your notification code with the same question so it is also helpful....Thanks

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: @AkshayChordiya , the RemoteControlClient is only for apis of pre lollipop, right? Why not surround that with an if(<=lollipop) statement?

Comment: @AkshayChordiya , the lockscreen control works after doing this, but why does the lockscreen metadata not get updated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I figured a solution for this. Thanks to [@ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) & [@user1549672](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1549672/user1549672)

1. Add [Audio Focus](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) as suggested by [@ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake)
2. Add Music Intent `BroadcastReceiver` can be found if searched on Google & also on Official Android Docs
3. Write the `setupMediaSession()` given in my question above
4. **VERY IMPORTANT** Mention the `Flags` properly
5. Write `MediaSessionCallbacks` also available above
6. **VERY IMPORTANT** Update the `MediaSession` on `MediaPlayer#onPause()`, `MediaPlayer#onStart()` & finally when new song is played (also includes next & previous played) mentioned by [@user1549672](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1549672/user1549672)
7. Release the `MediaSession` object in `onDestory()`

Well that's all, most of the material (code) is available above. This question took couple of months to solve, finally it's done.

Comment: bro how you are displaying the lock scree media controller

Comment: @SAVVY I think this piece of line tells the Android OS to show music controls on the lockscreen.

`mMediaSessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);`

Comment: bhai can you tell me where I am doing wrong I am not getting lock screen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251734/lockscreen-for-media-control-is-not-showing-in-android

Comment: bro I followed what you said but dont know where I am making mistake bounty is onn but still no ans hope you may guide me

Comment: Bro i am able to get the lockscreen but it show only play pause button how i can show the next and previous button any advice?

Comment: @SAVVY Great. To show other buttons you need to set actions using `mMediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setState(playState, position(), 1.0f)
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE| PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT|PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS).build());`

Comment: @Akshay Chordiya as i see above and your answer it is difficult to implement this so if it is possible so can you please provide complete answer it will very helpful for me PLEASE SHARE YOUR ANSWER HERE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595575/how-to-set-this-type-of-view-for-a-notification thaks in advance

Answer (score 11):

While not strictly required for `MediaSession`, `RemoteControlClient` used on API14-19 devices, does require [audio focus](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) and it is 100% strongly recommended for all media playback.

Adding lines such as:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)
    getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this,
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
if (result != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
    return; //Failed to gain audio focus
}
```

Before playing any media should gain audio focus and show controls.

Comment: I'm already using it, but I was using it below `MediaSessionCompat`, I shifted the `AudioManager` code above it.
Yet it doesn't seem to work on Emulator

Comment: You'll need to include a lot more code in your question then, ideally your entire service and your Manifest entry for the Media Button Receiver

Comment: Facing the same issue. Can anyone help please?

Comment: @RisingUp
I felt, I'm the only one facing this issue. Hopefully we solve it

Comment: Your code is working fine for me on an API 16 emulator - check out [this super minimal example](https://gist.github.com/ianhanniballake/15dce0b233b4f4b23ef8) that shows lock screen controls for me.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'll check your minimal code, hope it work

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'll check your minimal code, hope it work. BTW is any permission in Manifest required?

Comment: @Aky - the only ones I had was `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` for downloading the mp3 I was testing with - I stripped even that out of the example (there's actually no playback at all in the example - just simulated). I did note that things in general worked much better on a real device than the emulator, so perhaps the emulator just isn't any good at testing these type of things.

Comment: @ianhanniballake
I'm playing with your minimal example, I don't know but I'm damn pissed by this issue

Comment: @ianhanniballake @RisingUp
Mainly I don't understand, how come it works on `Lollipop` & not on `Pre-Lollipop`

Comment: Have you tried it on a real device? You may be chasing ghosts and emulator issues.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I sometimes usually try on real device but when I don't get real device I try on emulator, the minimal example was tested on Emulator & I'm planning to test it on Real Device

Comment: @Aky - since the sample I provided works, the problem is with your code. Can you include any parts of your code that differ from the sample provided?

Comment: @ianhanniballake
You suggest me what should I attach?
Because I have added most of the things required.

Comment: the simple example that ianhanniballake posted worked for me!

Comment: @user1549672 Superb, I'm yet stuck with this issue & have less time

Answer (score 5):

Finally I got an answer to your's and my problem .Issue is you need to specify actions (mMediaSessionCompat.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE) even while updating mediasession. So your code should now look like

```
  private void updateMediaSessionMetaData() {
     int playState = mPlaying
            ? PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING
            : PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED;
           mMediaSessionCompat.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, getArtist())
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, getAlbum())
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, getSongTitle())
                .putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, duration())
                .putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TRACK_NUMBER, mSongPosn)
                .putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_NUM_TRACKS, songs.size())
                .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, albumArt)
                .build());
mMediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setState(playState, position(), 1.0f)
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE| PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT|PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS).build());
```

UPDATE : Added code for MediaCallback & Receiver

```
   private final class MediaSessionCallback extends MediaSessionCompat.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
        pausePlayer();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        pausePlayer();
    }
    public void onSeekTo(long pos) {
        seek(pos);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSkipToNext() {
        playNext();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSkipToPrevious() {
        playPrev();
    }
}
```

Receiver :

```
 public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PAUSE);
            intent1.setClass(context,
                    com.xyz.service.MusicService.class);
            // send an intent to our MusicService to telling it to pause the
            // audio
            context.startService(intent1);

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)) {

            KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) intent.getExtras().get(
                    Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if (keyEvent.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                return;

            switch (keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK:
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                    Intent intentToggle = new Intent(
                            MusicService.ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK);
                    intentToggle.setClass(context,
                            com.xyz.service.MusicService.class);
                    context.startService(intentToggle);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                    Intent intentPlay = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY);
                    intentPlay.setClass(context,
                            com.xyz.service.MusicService.class);
                    context.startService(intentPlay);

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                    Intent intentPause = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PAUSE);
                    intentPause.setClass(context,
                            com.xyz.service.MusicService.class);
                    context.startService(intentPause);

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                    Intent intentNext = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_NEXT);
                    intentNext.setClass(context,
                            com.xyz.service.MusicService.class);
                    context.startService(intentNext);

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                    Intent intentPrev = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PREV);
                    intentPrev.setClass(context,
                            com.xyz.service.MusicService.class);
                    context.startService(intentPrev);

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested on real device without using track number & number tracks unfortunately it didn't work again.

Comment: @Aky Did you .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE both while setting up Mediasession & updating media session both?

Comment: I'll check that out, but are you using `MediaStyle` for Notification

Comment: Is that the reason why 'MediaSessionCompat'  is not working on Pre Lollipop

Comment: It still works. Just try my code and tell me if you get stuck.

Comment: Can you put your whole service,receiver & related code in pastebin or something. Let me check your code on my device.

Comment: Try this one .I have modified your code to remove some unnecessary stuffs. http://pastebin.com/Kut7JEYa

Comment: I'm glad, I'll try it out & let you know

Comment: I tested it & didn't work. I'll perform few more tests for sure results. PS Used real device

Comment: I wonder what's going wrong. I would suggest you to break code into small snippets and test functionality one by one.

Comment: Ohhkay, I'll try that too

Comment: can you please provide me the full code i am stuck from last month on this and unable to handle some problems like How to get mediasession callbacks? What is the hierarchy to set all things like mediasession, callbacks, AudioFocus, PlaybackStatus? also i don't know how and why we use playbackstatus