# How to make lock screen notification for media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, android-notifications, lockscreen

I am trying to get lock screen in the mobile I am able to get every thing work like notification and other things of my app but when I try to display the lock screen it is not working at all for android M.

```
private void initMediaSession() throws RemoteException {
    if (mediaSessionManager != null) return; //mediaSessionManager exists
    ComponentName mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MediaButtonReceiver.class);

    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "AudioPlayer", mediaButtonReceiver, null);
    //Get MediaSessions transport controls
    transportControls = mediaSession.getController().getTransportControls();
    //set MediaSession -> ready to receive media commands
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
    //indicate that the MediaSession handles transport control commands
    // through its MediaSessionCompat.Callback.
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaButtonIntent.setClass(this, MediaButtonReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
    mediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(pendingIntent);
    //Set mediaSession's MetaData
    updateMetaData();
    // passing the data


    // Attach Callback to receive MediaSession updates
    mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        // Implement callbacks
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();
            messagesent();
            a = false;
            resumeMedia();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            messagesent();
            a = true;
            pauseMedia();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToNext() {
            super.onSkipToNext();

            skipToNext();
            updateMetaData();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToPrevious() {
            super.onSkipToPrevious();

            skipToPrevious();
            updateMetaData();
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            removeNotification();
            //Stop the service
            pauseMedia();
            messagesent();
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(long position) {
            super.onSeekTo(position);
        }
    });
}

private void updateMetaData() {
    //replace with medias albumArt
    // Update the current metadata
    MediaMetadataCompat.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();

    String artist;
    if (activeAudio.getArtist() != null) {
        artist = activeAudio.getArtist();
    } else {
        artist = "unknown";
    }
    String album;
    if (activeAudio.getAlbum() != null) {
        album = activeAudio.getAlbum();
    } else {
        album = "Album";
    }
    Bitmap albumArt;
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(activeAudio.getAlbum_art());
    try {
        InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            albumArt = bitmap;
        } else {
            albumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.music);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        albumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.music);
    }
    metadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON, albumArt);
    metadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, albumArt);

    //lock screen icon for pre lollipop
    metadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ART, albumArt);
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_TITLE, activeAudio.getTitle());
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_SUBTITLE, activeAudio.getAlbum());
    metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, album);
    metadataBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TRACK_NUMBER, 1);
    metadataBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_NUM_TRACKS, 1);

    mediaSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
}

private void buildNotification(PlaybackStatus playbackStatus) {

    /**
     * Notification actions -> playbackAction()
     *  0 -> Play
     *  1 -> Pause
     *  2 -> Next track
     *  3 -> Previous track
     */

    MediaControllerCompat controller = mediaSession.getController();
    MediaMetadataCompat mediaMetadata = controller.getMetadata();
    MediaDescriptionCompat description = mediaMetadata.getDescription();

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.customnotification);


    if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING || Singleton.getInstance().getMedia() == 1) {
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageButton2,
                R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_white_48dp);

        messagesent();

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton2, playbackAction(1));

    } else if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PAUSED || Singleton.getInstance().getMedia() == 2) {
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageButton2,
                R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_48dp);
        messagesent();

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton2, playbackAction(0));

    }

    views.setViewVisibility(R.id.imageView, View.VISIBLE);

    // Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);

    // PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    //         notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton3, playbackAction(3));
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton4, playbackAction(2));

    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageButton3,
            R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_circle_outline_white_36dp);
    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageButton4,
            R.drawable.ic_skip_next_circle_outline_white_36dp);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, description.getTitle());
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, description.getSubtitle());
    views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, description.getIconBitmap());


   NotificationCompat.Builder sta = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
   //  sta.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    sta.setContent(views);
    sta.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_audiotrack_white_24dp);
    sta.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0).setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()));


    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, sta.build());



}


public PendingIntent playbackAction(int actionNumber) {
    Intent playbackAction = new Intent(this, MediaService.class);
    switch (actionNumber) {
        case 0:
            // Play
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 1:
            // Pause
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 2:
            // Next track
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 3:
            // Previous track
            playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        case 4:
            playbackAction.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
            return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried to set the notification .setstyle but it is showing some error.
I followed the video of ian lake but it is still not working can some one help what I am doing wrong

Comment: Is the lockscreen background showing the album art?
Your problem is `Notification` not showing up right?

Comment: I made the custom notification and no nothing is getting shown in the background

Comment: If background is not getting changed then probably you missed something in the `MediaController` code. Did you follow the steps mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32656418/1904141 ?

Answer (score 3):

I followed the follow the following tutorial and get the output.

```
private Notification createNotification() {  
if (mMetadata == null || mPlaybackState == null) {
    return null;
}

Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mService);
int playPauseButtonPosition = 0;

// If skip to previous action is enabled
if ((mPlaybackState.getActions() & PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS) != 0) {
    notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev_gray,
            mService.getString(R.string.label_previous), mPreviousIntent);

    // If there is a "skip to previous" button, the play/pause button will
    // be the second one. We need to keep track of it, because the MediaStyle notification
    // requires to specify the index of the buttons (actions) that should be visible
    // when in compact view.
    playPauseButtonPosition = 1;
}

addPlayPauseAction(notificationBuilder);

// If skip to next action is enabled
if ((mPlaybackState.getActions() & PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT) != 0) {
    notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_next_gray,
            mService.getString(R.string.label_next), mNextIntent);
}

MediaDescription description = mMetadata.getDescription();

String fetchArtUrl = null;
Bitmap art = null;
if (description.getIconUri() != null) {
    // This sample assumes the iconUri will be a valid URL formatted String, but
    // it can actually be any valid Android Uri formatted String.
    // async fetch the album art icon
    String artUrl = description.getIconUri().toString();
    if (art == null) {
        fetchArtUrl = artUrl;
        // use a placeholder art while the remote art is being downloaded
        art = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mService.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
}

notificationBuilder
        .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
            .setShowActionsInCompactView(new int[]{playPauseButtonPosition})  // show only play/pause in compact view
            .setMediaSession(mSessionToken))
        .setColor(mNotificationColor)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setUsesChronometer(true)
        .setContentIntent(createContentIntent(description)) // Create an intent that would open the UI when user clicks the notification
        .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
        .setContentText(description.getSubtitle())
        .setLargeIcon(art);

setNotificationPlaybackState(notificationBuilder);
if (fetchArtUrl != null) {
    fetchBitmapFromURLAsync(fetchArtUrl, notificationBuilder);
}

return notificationBuilder.build();
```

}

and try to follow the [tutorial](http://sapandiwakar.in/android-media-player-lock-screen/)
as there is no issue in the android version it is just not showing the notification in lollipop also.Or you can even just copy the following tutoria also[tutorial](http://tutorialsface.blogspot.in/2014/07/music-player-with-notification-and-lock.html)
or

```
   Notification.MediaStyle style = new Notification.MediaStyle();

Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class );
intent.setAction( ACTION_STOP );
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder( this )
        .setSmallIcon( R.drawable.ic_launcher )
        .setContentTitle( "Media Title" )
        .setContentText( "Media Artist" )
        .setDeleteIntent( pendingIntent )
        .setStyle( style );
```

try to use the notification style thats the issue if you are able to get the style the lock screen will show automaticaly .

Answer (score 1):

At first check if your app is working using targetSdkVersion 22 on build.gradle. If it works then you have Marshmallow runtime permission related issue. Add required permissions on Manifest and run your initMediaSession() if the permissions are granted. Details [Link1](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
and [Link2](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/).

If this does not help you then provide your error details.

Comment: bro it is working properly for some device but it is not showing for lolipop device. properly

Comment: The app is not getting crash bro but it is not showing any lock screen.